# How to evaluate a soft Voting classifier being trained on some data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

I have taken 3 classification models,

```
clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
clf2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)
clf3 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
```

I am passing them to voting classifier as parameters and choose soft voting.

```
eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dt', clf1), ('knn', clf2), ('svc', clf3)], voting='soft', weights=[2,1,2])

clf1 = clf1.fit(titanic_train1,y_train)
clf2 = clf2.fit(titanic_train1,y_train)
clf3 = clf3.fit(titanic_train1,y_train)
eclf = eclf.fit(titanic_train1,y_train)
```

Here i am getting error ,AttributeError: 'VotingClassifier' object has 
    no attribute 'best_score_'

```
print("CvScore",eclf.best_score_)
print("Train accuracy",eclf.score(titanic_train1, y_train))
```

I want to find best tuning parameters for this model?

Comment: VotingClassifier simply takes the probabilities of individual estimators and returns the class with maximum probability. What do you actually want to access through `best_score_`? You said you are getting an error, but did not describe what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

VotingClassifier does not have a best_score_ attribute.  You can look at the scikit-learn documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) to see that the best_score_ attribute is missing.

If you're trying to get a cross validation score you need to use something like [K-Fold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) or [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) where K-Fold will give you an idea for how well the classifier generalizes to naive data and GridSearchCV will help determine the best parameter configuration for the model.